# Dynamic @returns in JSDoc, based on @param value

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Is there a way to document the function, so vscode-intellisense knows that `getObject("player")` returns a `Player` type and `getObject("bullet")` returns a `Bullet` type?

```js
/**
 * @param  {string} type
 * @return {????}
 */
function getObject(type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'player': return new Player();
        case 'bullet': return new Bullet();
    }
}
```

An example of this functionality would be `document.createElement(...)`.

`document.createElement("canvas")` => intellisense knows it's a `HTMLCanvas` type.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with jsdocs.

`document.createElement` uses typescript function overload definitions for its behavior. You could also use a [`*.d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) this way:

```
declare function getObject(x: 'player'): Player;
declare function getObject(x: 'bullet'): Bullet;
```